# Magento 1: Change Email Body from RAWBody to HTMLBody / TextBody

Tags: magento-1.9, email

All emails sent by the Magento system have only a RAWBody according to IMAP. Is it possible to change the email body to HTMLBody or TextBody?

Can anyone tell if this problem affects Magento or the email server settings?

Anyway, I need to parse the emails for a CRM system, is there an easy way?

// Looks like an Zend_mail problem issue. Also i have problems with the encoding. Its stated utf-8 but i isnt utf-8. This is what the IMAP return looks like

RawBody:

Return-Path: Received: from localhost ([2a01:4f8:171:18e2::2]) by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id v16sm24477054wrt.12.2019.10.02.09.07.05 for 
(version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128); Wed, 02 Oct 2019 09:07:05 -0700 (PDT) Message-ID: 
 Reply-To: email@email.com To: =?utf-8?B?aW5mbw==?= Subject: =?utf-8?B?SWhyZSBBbmZyYWdlIGF1ZiBSZWxhZ2lvLmRlIC0gQW50b25pbyBTYW5jaGV6ICYgQmVyZW5nYXIgU2NobWlkdA==?= From: email Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 16:07:05 +0000 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Content-Disposition: inline MIME-Version: 1.0 =0A=0A=0AName: username=0AEmail: email=0ATelefon: 01234345=0ANachricht: rehgcghgf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to admin

```
system -> Transactional Emails -> add new template 

from Load default template section load **contact Form**
```

change as per your need and save template

now go to

system -> configuration -> general -> contact -> change Email Template

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new custom module to override core contact email template type in Magento 2.

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Magento_Contact" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

In above code, I've added `type="html"` to set contact email template type to HTML.

After your changes, run the deployment commands.

> **Edit: For Magento 1**

Create a custom module and put below code in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <template>
            <email>
                <contacts_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
                    <type>html</type><!-- same xpath as in the original config file -->
                </contacts_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: im not using magento 2...dunno why someone edited it to magento 2. magento 2 is for idiots.

Comment: You've not specified the version of your Magento. Please wait a while, I'm updating my code for M1

Comment: Updated my answer for the M1 version as well. Please check.

Comment: i am very grateful for your help. the problem cannot be solved because the problem affects all emails. i have changed the description and redescribed the problem.

but your solution is correct to display HTML content in RAWBody, which is interpreted correctly by email programs.